# i was trying to make my grid responsive using grid-template and media query

Tags: html, css

> im new to  CSS and was exploring how to display one item in the first row but display 2 items in the second row  when the size of the viewport is greater than 800px. but when size of viewport is less than that ,all the item should be displayed in three different rows instead .

below is a code snippet for the same
thank you !!

```css
@media (max-width:800px)
{
    .parent
    {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;  
    grid-template-areas: "first" "second" "third";    
    }
}
.parent
{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;  
    grid-template-areas: "first first" "second third";
}

.first{
    grid-area:first;
    background-color:blue;
}
.second{
    grid-area:second;
    background-color:red;
}
.third
{
    grid-area:third;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="first div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
<div class="second div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="third div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query rules don't take precedence over other rules, they still work within the context of the cascade. Just move the media query below the original `.parent` styles.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "first first" "second third";
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-areas: "first" "second" "third";
  }
}


.first {
  grid-area: first;
  background-color: blue;
}

.second {
  grid-area: second;
  background-color: red;
}

.third {
  grid-area: third;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
  <div class="second div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="third div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to downvote other answer :)

Comment: @Alessio I didn't down vote your answer. I only left the comment. There would be no reason to  down vote yours, since it was correct except for the `screen and`.