# Responsive Menu won't disappear on resize to desktop screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a website and I have created a simple responsive menu which will display when the screen size is below 885px (max-width:884px).

The menu had a standard inline display above screen size of 884px and below that (for mobile devices), has a hamburger menu which opens and closes a full window sized block display menu when toggle clicked.

When I refresh the page or load it up, everything is fine. However when I resize back to desktop screen size the hamburger icon still appears.

I have tried various different techniques using both CSS and JavaScript but to no avail.

In JavaScript, I have tried adding and removing classes, tried to make use of the `matchMedia` method and other ways but they have not worked.

```js
function navOpen() {
  var ovrly = document.getElementById("nav");
  var opn = document.getElementById("open");
  var cls = document.getElementById("close");
  ovrly.style.width = "100%";
  ovrly.style.display = "inline";
  opn.style.display = "none";
  cls.style.display = "block";
}

function navClose() {
  var ovrly = document.getElementById("nav");
  var opn = document.getElementById("open");
  var cls = document.getElementById("close");
  ovrly.style.width = "0%";
  cls.style.display = "none";
  opn.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* MAIN NAVIGATION */

#nav {
  display: inline;
}

#overlay-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: right;
}

#overlay-nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#overlay-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

#open {
  display: none;
}

#close {
  display: none;
}


/* RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION */

@media screen and (max-width:884px) {
  #nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #open,
  #close {
    color: #F2F2F2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
  }
  #overlay-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #0D0D0D;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 65px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D92938;
  }
  #overlay-nav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
  }
  #overlay-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a id="close" class="txtWhite" onclick="navClose()">&times;</a>
  <div id="overlay-nav" class="show">
    <li><a href="about" title="Find out more about us">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="news" title="Get all the latest news here">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact" title="Get in touch with us">CONTACT</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="open" class="txtWhite showmenu" onclick="navOpen()">&#9776;</a>
```

Comment: Move your `@media screen and (max-width:884px)` styles below the other responsive nav styles. Media queries are not more specific in the cascade of styles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i was trying to make my grid responsive using grid-template and media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536108/i-was-trying-to-make-my-grid-responsive-using-grid-template-and-media-query)

Comment: In the actual full CSS file they actually are the other around in terms of their position on the sheet its just when I copied and pasted them into this topic I put the "@media screen" code in first then the one underneath

Comment: Then update your question, because that's the information we have to go on and based on that, what I posted would be the answer. And also post the rest of your navigation. Only giving us the drop down is not useful.

Comment: @disinfor sorry about that my mistake new to stackoverflow I have updated the code with everything in the right order now.

Comment: fixed it I created a new media query and then after that, used the ids for the open and close buttons and applied hidden visibility in CSS to them